# App Insight Not available, keeps showing app offline or SDK is old

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are using .NET CORE 3.0 web application. We **haven't included** any App Insight Nuget package for App Insight. But we have enabled the appinsight directly from Azure Portal. After doing this, I'm expecting the server request, failures and live metrics to display.

But I keep getting this error on live metrics even though app is running:
*Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK*
[image]

We didn't have to include any appinsight nuget packags for 2.7 NET CORE version. Any idea why no metrics being displayed?

Answer (score 8):

As clearly stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#get-started) you **have to** include some NuGet packages:

> **Get Started**
>
> - If you haven't yet install Application Insights in your web app, do that now.
> - In addition to the standard Application Insights packages Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector is required to enable Live Metrics stream.
> - Update to the latest version of the Application Insights package. In Visual Studio, right-click your project and choose Manage Nuget packages. Open the Updates tab, and select all the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.* packages.
> - Redeploy your app.
> - In the Azure portal, open the Application Insights resource for your app, and then open Live Stream.

If you don't include those packages some telemetry is send to App Insights, but this telemetry won't be shown in the Live Metrics stream.

Comment: So we need to manage instrument app insight keys within Json? There is an option to assign appinsight service for app service with in azure portal. I thought this later option would install relevant dlls and configs?

Comment: *I thought this later option would install relevant dlls and configs* -> No unfortunately it doesn't. It does run an extra process to collect telemetry but it won't touch your code/assemblies.

Comment: So net core 3.1 requires us to use nuget package?

Comment: It is not the .Net Core version that requires it. It is the Live Metrics Stream. If you want to see that working you'll need to add the nuget packages. If you are just interested in the telemetry but don't really care about the Live Metrics Stream then you do not have to.

Answer (score 0):

Got confirmation from Microsoft that in order to use Appinsight with net core 3.1, we need to use SDK. Other option is to downgrade 3.0.

They said. Net Core 3.1 will be supported by AZURE portal Appinsight in near future