# Why do i get "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK' when i turn on live metrics in App insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have turned on Application Insights in my Web App, but when i go to live metrics in Application Insights I get the above error "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK' .

What do i need to turn on in Azure ?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You can refer this post [My web app doesn't show Live Metrics](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c96ee9c-99ba-4f8f-bc65-083d291a2772/my-web-app-doesnt-show-live-metrics?forum=ApplicationInsights), if it works for you, pls let me know.

Comment: When it says that you need to install "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web nuget package" Is that in the Visual Studio solution ? So do i need to add it and redeploy ? Reason i ask is that I have a .net api app and Application Insights is fine with that app service, i didnt need to install any nuget package for Application Insights.I thought that   by enabling Insights it would modify the App configfile .     This app receives requests GET,POST etc . I just want to simply see where the requests have been initiated from.

Comment: Everyone’s problems are different. You can [refer to another document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964759/app-insight-not-available-keeps-showing-app-offline-or-sdk-is-old). If nothing works, it is recommended to share your sample code, create a new sample code, and pay attention to personal information and confidential information.

Comment: I've met the situation of 'your app is offline', that's because I haven't running my program which has integrate azure app insights when I debug in visual studio or I haven't start my app service in azure or I've started my program/app but I set the wrong instrument key in my code or the setting is replaced by environment, e.g. azure app service -> configuration ->APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY will cover the instrument key in your code.

Comment: I have checked the instrument key for my configured Application Insights, and it is the same as the value in the app service under azure app service -> configuration ->APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY . Also the app service is actually running. So cant really see why  Live Metrics will give "app is offline"

Comment: So instead I used App Service -> Monitoring-> Logs and performed a kutso query bringing back all Server Requests.  requests
| summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 30m)
| render timechart  Imassuming that will give me all requests to the app service ?

Comment: @Abbey app service -> application insights -> view app insights data -> transaction search to see all the request.

Comment: Yes that particular navigation worked.

Comment: The best approach is to open a support ticket. Your scenario should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try it by using the latest application insights packages, or downgrade it. If it's not working, you'd better submit a support ticket.

As a workaround, you can use Logs feature or Search feature in application insights in azure portal. From there, you can also see these logs.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and message in Azure Portal with App Insights, Live metrics and Application Map not working. After browsing several solution descriptions I would like to give you the essence of my solution.

First of all: I started from scratch and straight forward. I had no firewall issue.
But in addition to the answer here on [social.msdn.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c96ee9c-99ba-4f8f-bc65-083d291a2772/my-web-app-doesnt-show-live-metrics?forum=ApplicationInsights) I will give you my way in more details.
Be aware: This solution was developed and tested using .Net 6.0 with EF 6.0.

I require all prerequisites for using an azure web app are set up!

I did

1. setting up necessary azure resources for running a web app using azure cli (there are many resources out there helping you getting around)
2. a simple .Net 6 Web app that can be published to azure web app
3. setting up application insights in azure
4. connecting app insights with web app in azure
5. dotnet publish
6. run the web app (.azurewebsites.net)

I add following code to my .Net 6 web app StartUp Class to enable Application Insights telemetry

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection*
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}...
```

therefore Nuget Package

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore (for me v2.20.0)

was necessary to install.

After that still no data was send to telemetry.

Live metrics say:
"Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK"
Application Map was not showing anything

**further Nuget Packages you need:**

> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector (v2.20.0)
>
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web (v2.20.0)

After that still no data was send to telemetry.

Last but lot least it was my fault:
After redeploying my azure setup for dev (all by *Infratructure as code*) the Application Insights InstrumentationKey had changed.
So always be sure that InstrumentationKey and ConnectionString are properly set  in appsettings.json.

```
{
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "GUID",
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=GUID;IngestionEndpoint=https://<location>.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/"
  }...
}
```

You can find the instrumentationKey in overview blade of your Application Insights in Azure Portal as well as using azure cli

> az monitor app-insights component show --app *yourappinsightsname* -g *yourressourcegrouname* --query instrumentationKey -o tsv

Hint: If you connect Application Insights using Visual Studio (2022 in my case) it will automatically insert Application Insights configuration to your appsettings.json. If you use appsettings.{env}.json be sure
you get them changed also id needed.

All that results in

ApplicationInsights working locally (when set in appsetting.development.json)
Application Map - now working
Live metrics - now working

Hope it helps like it did to me!