# Enable Live Metrics on Application Insights for a Docker based Python Function App

Tags: python, docker, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a Docker based Python Function App running, which is connected to an Application Insights resource. I get all the usual metrics, but the Live Metrics fails telling me "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK".

I am using the `azure-functions/python:4-python3.9-appservice` image as a base. If I remember correctly I was able to view Live Metrics when I simply deployed a Function App via ZIP deploy, but since switching to Docker this option has disappeared. Online I'm not able to find the right information to fix this or to determine if it is even possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do i get "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK' when i turn on live metrics in App insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66003480/why-do-i-get-not-available-your-app-is-offline-or-using-an-older-sdk-when-i-t)

Comment: [App Insight Not available, keeps showing app offline or SDK is old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964759/app-insight-not-available-keeps-showing-app-offline-or-sdk-is-old) and [App Insights integration with existing Function App](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/706),

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently Live Metric Stream for Python is not supported.

The **[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream)** says that currently supported languages are **.NET, Java** and **Node.js**.

For achieving this you can refer the [alternate solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/46110/application-logging-for-azure-functions-in-python.html) given by @[AJG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/ajg-8960/) for that you have to create a **LogHandler** and write the messages into Cosmos DB container. It will stream into console.