# Application Insights Live Metric for Virtual Directory Apps

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an App Service on azure. It contains 2 web app set in 2 different virtual directory. There is no web app in the root folder. I have configure the Application Insight for both project in Visual Studio and publish each app to their azure virtual directory. But nothing is showing up in Live Metric of the Application Insight of the App Service. All I see is : "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK" .

Comment: While I'm checking on this, to better assist you, could you please describe on "There is no web app in the root folder.", how exactly have you configured your app? What's the application framework? 

-By default, Azure App Service points the root virtual application path `(/)` to the root directory of the deployed application files (D:\home\site\wwwroot).

Comment: I understand that the Live Metrics for root API shows-up fine now. To enable Application Insights ensure it is both activated in the Azure Portal and that the Application Insights NuGet package is included. Review language specific [guidelines][https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#get-started]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  **Application insight could only run on root website**.

BTW, the way you set up virtual applications may have some mistakes. You should set as below:

[image]

For more details, you could refer to the article-[Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

Also you will have to add the app insights SDK to all the app and be sure you set InstrumentationKey for each as well.

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964759/app-insight-not-available-keeps-showing-app-offline-or-sdk-is-old?rq=1) thread for similar kind of issue.

Comment: The directories are setup properly. I added a root API with just a HomeController. Now I see Live Metrics but only for that root API. Nothing for the Virtual Directories. I have install Insight SDK the same way for all 3 Apps (root and Virtual applications).